# Trying to create a button to scroll to al element, but the script ain't working

Tags: html, jquery

in the html i have 3 buttons with id="button" that correspond to different sections with their ids
Here is the script,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").on('click', function(event) {

    if (this.hash !== "") {
      event.preventDefault();

      var hash = this.hash;
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 1500, function(){

        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually can't have more than one element with the same ID, every element need to have different ID's or the same class.

Try to give different ID's and let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without javascript would be,

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
html{
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
#sec1, #sec2, #sec3{
height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#sec1">Go to one</a> |
<a href="#sec2">Go to two</a> |
<a href="#sec3">Go to three</a><br><br>
<div id="sec1" style="background-color: lightgreen">Section one</div>
<div id="sec2" style="background-color: lightyellow">Section Two</div>
<div id="sec3" style="background-color: lightblue">Section Three</div>
</body>
</html>
```